# OOP - Python class/R analogue

Tags: python, r

How would I construct this OOP logic in R ?

I've been doing some reading around S4 but struggling to translate.

```
class myclass(object):

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo 
        self.bar = self.cal_bar()
  
    @classmethod
    def some_func(self):
 
        global VAR
        t = do.something(VAR)
        return t
```

Comment: Have you thought of using Reference classes or even R6? Those seems to be much closer to the python/c++ classes

Comment: What does your R attempt look like? Which part in particular were you unable to accomplish? R is primarily a functions language so trying to force on OO paradigm on it isn't always the best idea, but there are packages that can fake object-like behavior, though that's not exactly the norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R has several class systems from which S3 and S4 are most common while Reference classes, R6 (and some none-standard systems like R.oo and proto) look somewhat closer to what is known from C++ or Java.

Here an example with **Reference classes**:

```r
myclass <- setRefClass("myclass",
  fields = c("foo"),
  methods = list(
     bar = function() {
       t <- 2 * .self$foo
       t
     }
   )
)

 
obj <- myclass(foo=2) 

obj$bar()
```

... and an example with **S4**:

```r
setClass("myS4class", representation(foo = "numeric"))

setGeneric("bar", function(obj, ...) standardGeneric("bar"))

setMethod("bar", "myS4class",
          function(obj, ...) {
            2 * obj@foo
          }
)          

obj <- new("myS4class", foo=2)

bar(obj)
```

Reference classes and R6 are cool and really flexible. They are sometimes advantageous, but in most cases S3 and S4 are more natural in R. It took me a while myself to realize this. The so-called functional approach of S3 and S4 looks different from what we know from other languages, but is convenient for a data centered analysis.

This is of course opinionated, so I suggest to try it out. The internet has many resources about this, here two examples:

- https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html
- https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/reference-class/